# how to set reponse header last-modified for static files like pictures in IIS 7.5 and above

Tags: html, iis-7.5, httpresponse

A service provider who is downloading images, videos and audio files from a number of download servers is asking to set Last-Modified Response Header to the current date of the files to allow them to identify currently updated files unter the same URL.
Looking around I found a lot about the Header but how can I add the header to respones for static files and make sure it is actually the last-modified date of the specific file?
Or is IIS smart enough to do that by itself if I add the header name in the IIS settings for the site?

Answer (score 0):

Grab a tool like Fiddler (https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) and take a look the response headers as they are out of the box.  The Last-Modified header should match the Modified Date shown on the files.

Give a read thru the Specification for Last-Modified under 14.29 (https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html)   Assuming IIS conforms to that (which I believe it does) you should be set without making any modifications to your webserver.